# Incrementing variable between PHP requests

Tags: php, persistence

I am writing a PHP script which, upon a request, will make a call to a SOAP service with various parameters, some of which are taken from the request.

However, the particular SOAP service I am using requires that each request includes a unique ID, which in this case needs to increment for each request. It must not be based on time, and must be unique for each request, however it does not matter if values are skipped.

Using a MySQL data base to store a single value seems massively overkill. I have thought about storing and loading it into a file, but the issue of race conditions springs to mind.

I do have complete access to the server, which will be some kind of Linux flavour dedicated to this task.

Is there a simple way this can be achieved?

Comment: SESSION and COOKIE are another ways to reach persistence

Comment: Memcache or something. But in my opinion thats oversized too. Do each number has to be bigger than the one before or just a different id?

Comment: $i++? well, just saying,

Comment: This is perfect example where Redis and Memcache can be used.

Comment: @MarkNg in a stateless language like php? To OP - any persistent storage will do - is this the only need for persistence in the whole app? If not use whatever to already have.

Comment: Easiest solution would be to store it in a flat file with file_put_contents and file_get_contents. Memcache would be overkill for just an incrementing number that has no value beyond satisfying your SOAP requirements.

Comment: @TimoF., they have to be incrementing for some reason...

Comment: @Practically my concern with this approach was that if two requests were made in quick succession, there could be a race condition in that the second could load the same value from the file before the first has written the new value.

Comment: @emorris I think then you'll go the best with Memcache or similar (like I and others mentioned before). Would be good if you leave a comment later how you solved this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is how I achieved this in the end. After considering the various options, databases and the various caching options seemed a bit overkill. In addition, caching, cookies and sessions seem to be designed to be relatively temporary, whereas I was really looking for a non-volatile solution.

This is what I came up with - a simple file locking solution. I hadn't realised PHP could deal with file locks but on discovering this, it seems the best way to go.

This example acquires an exclusive lock on the file, before reading and updating the value. If it hits max int, it resets. Then it waits for 5 seconds. If the script is called a few times in quick succession, observe that each request will wait for the lock to be release from the previous before continuing.

What's nice is, as this is PHP, non-existent file, invalid contents etc, will just cause the value to default to zero.

```
<?php

$f = fopen('sequence_num.txt', 'r+');

echo "Acquiring lock<br />\n";
flock($f, LOCK_EX);

echo "Lock acquired, updating value<br />\n";
$num = intval(fread($f, strlen(PHP_INT_MAX)));
echo "Old val = " . $num;
if ($num >= PHP_INT_MAX) {
    $num = 0;
} else {
    $num++;
}
echo " New val = " . $num;
echo "<br />Waiting 5 seconds<br />\n";
rewind($f);
ftruncate($f, 0);
fwrite($f, $num);
sleep(5);

echo "Releasing lock<br />\n";
flock($f, LOCK_UN);
fclose($f);
```

Answer (score -1):

Before any new request get incremental value using PHP's `time()` function, since time will be unique for each request.

```
 $increment_id = time();
```

Comment: `time()` won't be unique for each request, unless there is guaranteed to be no more than 1 request per second, which won't be the case. Even higher resolution time functions would not be able to be used, as the spec states that the value cannot be based on time, as per my post.

Answer (score -1):

If your application is single server you can try to store incremental ID in APC using:

```
$key = 'soap_service_name';
if (!apc_exists($key)) {
    apc_store($key, 0);
}
$id = apc_inc($key);
```

You need to check if a key exists in APC cache and set 0, otherwise `apc_inc` fails and returns `false`

If you have multiserver application you can store incremental id in Memcache/Redis (that needs to run additional service):

```
$key = 'soap_service_name';
$memcache = memcache_connect('memcache_host', 11211);
if (!empty(memcache_exists($memcache, $key))) {
    memcache_set($memcache, 0);
}
$id = memcache_increment($memcache, $key);
```

Same situation as APC if you call `memcache_increment` it will fail if key doesn't exists yet.

If that incremental ID should be stored persistently Redis would be more usefull because it has disk write of all data. It's kind of Memcache with disk write.

Comment: Looks like APC might be the way to go! I suppose their is a small race condition between checking the key exists exists and setting to zero if not, however this is probably extremely unlikely to occur in my case.

Answer (score -1):

If you're happy to use a float as a unique value use:

```
$unique_id = microtime(true);
```

If you wish to simply increment, you may do so using a session var:

```
/**
 * Get session increment.
 *
 * @param string $id
 * @param int $default
 * @return int
 */
function get_increment($id, $default = 0)
{
    if (array_key_exists($id, $_SESSION)) $_SESSION[$id] += 1;

    else $_SESSION[$id] = $default;

    return $_SESSION[$id];
}

var_dump(get_increment('unique_id'));
```